# Slick2d Cannot instantiate the type Game?

Tags: java, syntax-error, slick2d

Hey guyes i just started creating some programs or games with Slick2d.So the problem is that i am getting error like this:  instantiate the type Game.

The code:

```
public HelloWorld()

 public static final String gamename = "Game"

 {
    super(gamename);
 }

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException
{

}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException
{

}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
{
 g.drawString("Hello World", 100, 100);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException
{
 AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));

 app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
 app.start();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String gameName = "Game";

public HelloWorld() {
    super(gameName);
}

Init method correct
Update method correct
Render method correct

public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new HelloWorld());

    app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
    app.start();
}
```

I think you should do a few more tutorials before your post questions like this. Make sure you place my corrections inside of a HelloWorld class that extends BasicGame I think it is. The name has to be the same as my constructor. If you have absolutely no idea what I am talking about then search google for basic java tutorials.

Enjoy

P.s I am writing this from my phone so I have not tested the code